# Recursive function for list of lists

Tags: java, recursion, nested-lists

I have an object(of type 'Flows') which contains a list of type 'Flows'

```
class Flows{
 String id;
 String sequence;
 List<Flows> listOfFlows;
}
```

I want to get all the elements of all the nested lists (can have any number of nested list) into a single list. How can we achieve it through recursion in java?

Comment: You need to define what a `listOfFlows` looks like in a low level flow.  I would expect it to be `null` if it isn't used but this is germaine to any recursive solution to avoid throwing an NPE.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about something like:

```
void flattenFlows(Flows flows, List<Flows> flowsList)
{
    flowsList.add(flows);
    for (Flows f: flows.listOfFlows) {
        flattenFlows(f, flowsList);
    }
}
```

`flowsList` being the list you want to add all the flows to.

Edit: if it is possible for the list field to be null (as one commenter pointed out), add a null check:

```
void flattenFlows(Flows flows, List<Flows> flowsList)
{
    flowsList.add(flows);
    if(flow.listOfFlows!=null) {
        for (Flows f: flows.listOfFlows) {
            flattenFlows(f, flowsList);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to replace `flowsList.add(f);`  with `flowsList.add(flows);`

Comment: @N.berouain yes thank you. It happened because I moved it out of the inner loop in an edit. Oops

Comment: SInce this results in a list of low level flows, you will eventually get to a flow which has no list, just an empty place holder.  You should probably check for a `null` `ListOfFlows` before you try to iterate over it.  Your method threw an NPE when I tried it.  If the lists are allocated but  empty, then there is no problem.

Comment: @WJS added edit to account for the possibility of null lists